# MVC url routes not working after deployment on IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, model-view-controller, deployment, routes

I have a MVC app that works just fine on local, but when deployed on IIS all the routes return 404 not found. 
My browser shows me in some cases the layout but doesn't bring the data for that view and instead of that returns 404.

I will show you a method that works fine on local but in IIS fails.

```
    [Route("/Customer/CustomerDetails/{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> CustomerDetails(int id)
    {
        ApiResult<eCOM_Backend.Api.Responses.Customer> apiResult = await _customerApiMethods.CustomerDetailsAsync(id);
        eCOM_Backend.Api.Responses.Customer customerFromBackend = null;

        if (!apiResult.HasException)
        {
            customerFromBackend = apiResult.Result;
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Error", "Error", new { reason = apiResult.Exception });
        }

        CustomerViewModel customer = customerFromBackend.ToCustomerViewModel();
        return View(customer);
    }
```

When I call this method like: xxx/Customer/CustomerDetails/123 i get page not found.

I have tried lots of solutions(modified the appsettings.json, web.config etc.) but nothing worked so far.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is dotnet core. Make sure to provide correct physical path when you publish your app to IIS. Like `inetpub\wwwroot\YourAppName`. In IIS right click on your web app >Manage Website>Advanced Settings and make sure physical path ends on your app folder not `yourApp\someOtherFolder`